# Im getting an await outside yield error for a minigame command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im setting up a minigame in one of my cogs and i get this error, `discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.Games' raised an error: SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function (Games.py, line 78)` This command works fine in my main.py though. My code is below, Thanks!

```
@commands.command()
    async def numbergame(self, ctx):

      channel = ctx.channel
      await channel.send("Guess the number from 0-100 by writing the number in this channel!")
 
      number = random.randint(1,100)
 
      def check(m):
        return m.content.isdigit() and m.channel == channel and m.author == ctx.author
  
        while True:
           try:
               msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
           except asyncio.TimeoutError:
               return await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You are late to guess!")
           guess = int(msg.content)
           if guess == number:
               return await channel.send(f"Correct answer! {ctx.author.mention}")
           elif guess > number:
               await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your guess was too high!")
           elif guess < number:
               await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your guess was too low!")
```

Comment: Try unindenting by two spaces the `while True:` block.

Comment: @Enzo Do I unindent `while True:` 4 times?

Comment: No, just one. I mean, currently your `while` loop is inside the `check` function, when it's suppose to be inside the `numbergame` function. Just remove two spaces from every line inside your `while`.

Comment: @Enzo Ok i did that. But now all of my commands make the bot say it twice.

Comment: Have you idented everything correctly? I'll post an answer and see if this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop is inside the `check` function, when it's suppose to be inside the `numbergame` function. Try unindenting the while loop as follows:

```py
@commands.command()
async def numbergame(self, ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await channel.send("Guess the number from 0-100 by writing the number in this channel!")
 
    number = random.randint(1,100)
 
    def check(m):
        return m.content.isdigit() and m.channel == channel and m.author == ctx.author
  
    while True:
        try:
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, You are late to guess!")
        
        guess = int(msg.content)
        if guess == number:
            return await channel.send(f"Correct answer! {ctx.author.mention}")
        elif guess > number:
            await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your guess was too high!")
        elif guess < number:
            await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Your guess was too low!")
```

Comment: Yes this works but i most have done something to the rest of the code because the bot is replying to commands twice but works fine for my on_message event.